# Display content in ScrolledComposite

Tags: java, position, swt, scrolledcomposite

I want to create a view that users can zoom in and zoom out, so I planned to implement the view by using `ScrolledComposite`:

```
    ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    sc.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
```

The problem is: when the size of content is smaller than the size of scrolled composite, it always appears in the top left corner of the scrolled composite, even I tried `setBounds()` method of the control or `setOrigin()` of scrolled composite. In the example below, the display area content of `button` (100, 50) is smaller than the client area of `sc` (200, 200), the button always is shown at the top left corner even I tried set up some position for it to display in the scrolled composite.

```
    Button button = new Button(sc, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Button");
    button.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 50);
    sc.setContent(button);
    sc.setOrigin(30, 30);
```

The result I get is

[image: button is always at the top left corner]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use another `Composite` within the `ScrolledComposite` that will contain your button and possibly other content. On the inner or content `Composite` you will have the flexibility to place children as desired. The `ScrollComposite` doesn't use a layout, so you cannot control the placement of the children. Just like a `TabItem` will only allow you to `setContent` but not its placement.

```java
ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
sc.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);

Composite content = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
content.setSize(300, 300);
sc.setContent(content);

Button button = new Button(content, SWT.PUSH);
button.setText("Button");
button.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 50);
```

You can use the `content` composite in any way you like to layout the children. You may also now use a layout of your choice on the content composite to ensure the button always remains in center.

Comment: Please don't use `setBounds` on the `ScrolledComposite`. Use a layout for the `Shell` instead and specify the minimal size for the `ScrolledComposite`.